# Can a point $z$ which belongs to a closed set be a limit point of an open set which is disjoint from the closed set in topological space $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Say $X$ be a topological space, and $U$ and $V$ are open and closed sets respectively. Furthermore, $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. Now there is a point $z \in V$. Is it possible for the point $z$ to be a limit point for the open set $U$ which is disjoint from closed set $V$?

I have spent some time thinking on this, and seems like no, if I think in real line with Euclidean metric. But without introducing any metric and explicitly specifying the space (e.g. $\Bbb R$), can we deduce anything on the above statement?

Answer (score 3):

Sure: in $\Bbb R$ let $U=(0,1)$ and $V=[1,2]$, and let $z=1$.

In general let $X$ be a space and $F$ a closed subset of $X$. Let $U=X\setminus F$, which is of course open. If $F$ is not open, then $U$ is not closed, and there is necessarily a point $z\in F\cap\operatorname{cl}U$. Thus, the only time that there is *not* a pair of disjoint sets $U$ and $F$ with $U$ open, $F$ closed, and no point of $F$ a limit point of $U$ is when every closed subset of $X$ is also open. If $X$ is at least a $T_1$ space, this happens only when $X$ has the discrete topology.

Comment: I already though about this..but without even specifying the space, and metric, I mean!

Comment: @user3001408: I’ve extended the answer to give you more generality.